# Polynomial collocation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, control-theory, runge-kutta-methods

I was reading this article (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6b11/ff0dcf14991f7be50e354d85c932409a01d9.pdf) on colloaction method, where author has considered the IVP $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t))~~,~~t \in I=[0,T]~~,~~y(0)=y_0$$ Assume $f:I \times \Omega \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz. Now define a mesh $I_h=\{t_n : 0=t_0 <t_1< \ldots <t_N=T\}$ and $h_n=t_{n+1}-t_n$ and $h=\text{max} \{h_n: 0 \le n \le N-1 \}$ which is the step size. Now the solution will be approximated by an element $u_h$ of the polynomial space
$$S^{(0)}_m(I_h)=\{v \in C(I): v|_{[t_n,t_{n+1}]} \in \pi_m\}$$ Where $\pi_m$denotes the space of all real polynomials of degree less than or equal to $m$. Then author has written  that $dim\,S^{(0)}_m(I_h)\,=Nm+1$ , which im having a little difficulty to understand.Another doubt is does $u_h$ is getting approximated as a polynomial in every single intervals in the mesh or over the whole range ?

Also the author has defined a set of collocation points $X_h=\{t=t_n+c_ih_n:0 \le c_1 \le \ldots <c_m \le 1\}$ and its cardinality as 
$$\begin{align}|X_h|&=Nm ~\text{if}~0 < c_1 < \ldots <c_m \le 1 ,\\&=N(m-1)+1 ~\text{if}~0 < c_1 < \ldots <c_m = 1 ,m \ge 2 \tag{*}\end{align}$$I'm also having difficulty to understand $(*)$.
Also in general what is the difference between RK methods and Collocation , what extra advantage collocation provide over RK methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I start from the end: collocation methods are a subclass of implicit Runge-Kutta methods, which can be found even from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_method) of collocation methods.

Gauss-Legendre Runge-Kutta methods, for example, are collocation methods based on Gauss-Legendre quadrature points. Their advantages are multiple. For example, they have high order ($2s$ for a method on $s$ stages), and they have great properties in geometric problems (conservation of quadratic invariants, symplecticity...). Another class of collocation methods are the Radau methods, which are $A$ and $L$-stable, making them an extremely good candidate for integrating stiff equations (order $2s-1$ for $s$ stages).

Regarding the dimension of $S_m^{(0)}(I_h)$, you have $N$ intervals, and on each interval a polynomial of degree $m$. In total, therefore, you have $N\cdot (m+1)$ degrees of freedom, which give the dimension of the space. Or does it? You have to impose continuity at the internal extrema of the intervals, therefore you have $N-1$ constraints (free ends): therefore
$$
\dim{S_m^{(0)}(I_h)} = Nm + N - N + 1 = Nm+1.
$$
The only doubt I have about this, is that if you impose the initial condition you get an additional constraint, which would make the dimension just $Nm$. A similar reasoning yields the cardinality of the set $X_h$.

An excellent treatment of collocation methods, which is very accessible too, can be found in *Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I*, by Hairer, Norset, Wanner (within Chapter 2.7 in the second edition). The equivalence with RK methods is shown in details. In the other books by the same authors (without Norsett and/or with Lubich) *Solving ODEs II* and *Geometric Numerical Integration* collocation methods are more or less treated and appear ubiquitously.